# How did Polish (Prefix) Notation Simplify Reasoning?

Tags: notation, polish-notation

I've used both Polish and Reverse Polish (RPN) notation.  I get that using them one doesn't have to deal with varying evaluation order.  While the benefits to automatic computation (as in software) is clear, it's unclear how this aided human reasoning.

Can anyone explain how Polish Notation (or even RPN) simplified reasoning by people over infix notation?  I'll be happy with any examples or even references to additional reading.

Comment: Just a question: what would the reaction of somebody who has only learned Polish notation in logic (or for that matter in arithmetic) be when presented with the "habitual" syntax of logic (or of arithmetic)?

Comment: @MasB I agree the "benefits" of infix may just be that we're used to it.  In fact, the amount of scanning and moving around the line and remembering what goes first adds to the cognitive load.  However, are there more precise benefits that an alternate notation like Polish brings -- like a demonstration that solving equations is easier?  I've been playing a bit with solving a simple equation using both notations, and it looks like Polish Notation brings something to the table.  But I also figure that those more versed in it can give a deeper answer into this.

Comment: Polish notation makes proofs in mathemathemical logic that work by induction over the syntactic form of an expression a little simpler. It also makes life a bit simpler if you want to use syntactic constructs to construct models. The benefits are not that great, but it is useful to know about. Apart from brackets and commas, Polish notation and the usual notation are the same if you don't have infix operators.

Comment: @MasB: I think your question is hypothetical: I can't believe there is anyone on the planet who has learned Polish notation without any exposure to the traditional infix notations.

Comment: Back before calculators had loads of memory and capacity to interpret human notational conventions, RPN allowed you to enter in complex calculations without having to stop and write out intermediate results to be typed back in later. Your choices were either RPN, or immense pain. Even when memory and parentheses keys were added, you had only one memory slot and could not nest parentheses, so occasionally you still had to copy out results for later. But with RPN calculators, you didn't have to do that. It was always possible to order the calculation to obviate the need.

Comment: The means of converting traditional notation to RPN took some training, but it didn't take long to figure it out. And once you did, it made perfect sense. I still prefer to use an RPN calculator to a modern regular one, which I sometimes have to force to do intermediary calculations so its results follow my thought process.